# Inferring recursive expressions using Hindley Milner & constraints

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-inference, ml, hindley-milner

I am trying to infer the type of the following expression:

```
let rec fix f = f (fix f)
```

which should be given the type `(a -> a) -> a`

After using the bottom up algorithm (described in *generalizing hindley-milner type inference algorithms*) with the added rule below:

```
           a1, c1 |-BU e1 : t1     B = fresh var
---------------------------------------------------------
a1\x, c1 U {t' == B | x : t' in A} |-BU let rec x = e1 : t
```

i am left with the following type: `t1 -> t2`

and the following constraints:

```
t0 = fix
t1 = f
t2 = f (fix f)
t3 = f
t4 = fix f
t5 = fix
t6 = f

t3 = t1
t3 = t4 -> t2
t5 = t0
t5 = t6 -> t4
t6 = t1
```

I cant see how these constraints can be solved such that i am left with the type `(a -> a) -> a`. I hope it is obvious for someone to see were i am going wrong.

[full source code here](http://hpaste.org/68479)

Comment: Please note that `let rec` should be simply `let`, otherwise you're just defining a function `rec :: ((a -> b) -> a) -> (a -> b) -> b`.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame sorry code example wasnt in haskell but an ML style language.

Comment: Okay, it's just that you had the question tagged with "haskell" so I assumed that was the language you were working with.  Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't there be a `t7` for the first `fix f`? These give the constraints:

```
t7 = t2
t0 = t1 -> t7
```

From that you should be able to deduce that `t4 = t2` and then `t0 = (t2 -> t2) -> t2`.

Comment: you were spot on, i wasn't constraining B to t in the rule above!